# Roumadjade in southern France

Tags: étymologie

From *Thérèse Desqueyroux* (François Mauriac, 1927):

> le gâteau dénommé fougasse ou roumadjade
> *the cake called fougasse or roumadjade*

Footnote on these last terms:

> Fougasse est le nom donné à une brioche en couronne, faite dans le Sud-Ouest, qui s'apparente à la fouace d'Auvergne. Les dictionnaires du gascon ignorent le nom de roumadjade.
> *Fougasse is the name given to a crown-shaped brioche, made in the Southwest, which is related to the fouace of Auvergne. The name roumadjade does not appear in Gascon dictionaries.*

Perhaps we can do better than this editor. To me it looks like a possible Arabic term that would have come into Southwest France via Spain. Do the Arabic scholars among us have any inklings?

Comment: Not really related to _roumadjade_ (which I’ve never heard of), but… fougasse is neither a cake nor a brioche?!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No need to look for an Arabic origin.

This *fougasse* was likely including cheese, in Occitan: *formatge/fromatge*, but in the Gascon variant spoken in the *Sud-Ouest*, cheese is ***[hromatge](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/hromatge)***. With the regular *-ade* suffix meaning a cooking preparation (like *griller* gives *grillade* or lemon, lemonade), it was a ***hromatjada*** phonetically transcripted in French as ***roumadjade***. The French equivalent would be ***fromageade***.

That name is also used for the [**fromadjade**](https://www.cuisineaz.com/recettes/fromadjades-13173.aspx), a Pied-Noir dish that comes from the Balears where it is called ***[formatjada](https://ca.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formatjada)***.

Comment: Perceptive noticing of 'fromage' in 'roumadje'! Of course that makes sense. I'll remove the `arabic` tag for search reasons while leaving the reference to it in my context.

Comment: If you "squint" vocally (!) hard enough, you can plausibly hear the kinship between the 2 words :-) Something like fromage -> froumage -> 'roumage.

Comment: I never heard about the south-west "fougasse" (a crown brioche). However, when staying in French Riviera, I often buy a [fougasse](https://www.tasteatlas.com/fougasse) that is a traditional flat bread from Provence.

Comment: @Graffito Fougasse est un nom générique qui se décline en différentes spécialités en fonction des régions et pays ( [fouasse, *fogassa*, *focaccia*, *pogača*, *Pogatschen*...](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fougasse) ). La fougasse de Mauriac devait plus s'apparenter à la [fougasse de foix](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b5/Fougasse_de_Foix.jpg) pour ce qui est du contenu, pas de la forme.

Comment: @Frank La transformation de certains *F* initiaux en *H* est une caractéristique du gascon et de l'espagnol. Latin → espagnol : *filius* →  *hijo*, *ferro* → *hierro*,  *facere* → *hacer*,  *formosa* → *hermosa*. On a un rare cas en français: *foras* → *hors* (mais *fuera* en espagnol).

Comment: @jlliagre Bien reçu, l'évolution se suit très bien avec cette caractéristique.